# Webpack Environment Variable Performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, environment-variables

I was reading the [webpack performance best practices](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#set-node_env-to-production) when I came accross the following line:

> Be aware that checking the value of any environment variable incurs a performance penalty, and so should be done sparingly.

So my question is **why is checking the value of an environment variable (eg `process.env.NODE_ENV`) so costly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process.env` is not just a regular JavaScript object, but is implemented in C++. Crossing the boundary between the C++ runtime and JavaScript is pretty expensive, especially compared to a simple object access. See [v8 Engine - Why is calling native code from JS so expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874423/v8-engine-why-is-calling-native-code-from-js-so-expensive)
 for some of the reasons for that.

Accessing `process.env` heavily will indeed hurt the performance and can generally be avoided by caching the values you need. For example, React used to have the issue with [Server rendering is slower with npm react #812](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/812), which led to a performance cost of about 30%, because of the various `process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"` conditionals.

As long as you don't use `process.env` excessively (e.g. in loops), you shouldn't have to worry about the performance impact. For reference, the result of a benchmark shown in [Improving SSR Performance: process.env optimization](https://gist.github.com/exogen/97c6258ead108af26593):

> The results: 100 million accesses of a value on unaltered `process.env` took 32 seconds, while the same number of accesses on a plain-object `process.env` took 2 seconds.

Because `process.env` is part of Node.js and does not exist in the browser, you don't get any performance hits if you bundle up your code with webpack, as it provides the needed values (unless you configure webpack to target Node.js). Therefore any performance concerning `process.env` in webpack is related to the build process. The only code from the user that is executed by webpack and would affect the build time is anything in the config. For the most part this is completely irrelevant, except for anything that is called frequently, especially for every processed file. For example in loaders or any function defined to determine whether a rule should be applied to the given file, and to a lesser extent in plugins.